# WordPress creating settings page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to learn how to make custom dashboard pages and settings in WordPress. The tutorial I followed was pretty clear...but there's one very small thing that doesn't make sense to me.

There is a line of code near the bottom of my **funcions.php** in the `demo_footer_message_display()` function that says `option['message']`. I don’t understand where ‘message’ is ever defined. If it said option[‘footer_message’] that would make plenty of sense because ‘footer_message’ is the id of the field I’m dealing with.

The code works fine but I just don’t understand why? Where is ‘message’ ever defined as an index of the options array. Can anyone explain this to me?

PS. in case it's not obvious my settings page just has an input where you can enter some text in the footer of the theme.

### functions.php

> ```
> <?php
> /* --------------------------------------------*
>  * Menus
> /*---------------------------------------------*/
>
> // Adds the 'DEMO THEME OPTIONS' to the 'Settings' menu in WordPress
>
> function demo_add_options_page(){
>     add_options_page(
>             'Lindsay Demo Theme Options', //browser title
>             'Lindsay Demo Theme Options', // menu text
>             'manage_options',  // required capability of users to access this menu
>             'lindsay-demo-theme-options', // slug
>             'demo_theme_option_display' // name of function used to display content
>         );
> } 
> add_action('admin_menu', 'demo_add_options_page');
>
> /* --------------------------------------------*
>  * Sections, Settings, and Fields
> /*---------------------------------------------*/
>
> // Registers a new settings field on the 'Demo Theme Options' page
>
> function demo_initialize_theme_options(){
>
>     //section to be rendered on the new options page
>     add_settings_section(
>         'footer_section', //id 
>         'Footer Options', //title on screen
>         'demo_footer_options_display', //callback 
>         'lindsay-demo-theme-options'//ID of page 
>         );
>
>     //define the settings field
>     add_settings_field(
>         'footer_message', //ID of field
>         'Theme Footer Message', //label
>         'demo_footer_message_display', //callback 
>         'lindsay-demo-theme-options', // page 
>         'footer_section' // the section to add to
>         );
>
>     //Register the 'footer_message' setting with the 'General' section
>         register_setting(
>             'footer_section', //name of the group of settings
>             'footer_options' //name of option
>             );
> } //end demo_initialize_theme_options
>
> add_action('admin_init', 'demo_initialize_theme_options');
>
> /* --------------------------------------------*
>  * Callbacks
> /*---------------------------------------------*/
>
> function demo_theme_option_display(){
> ?>
>     <div class="wrap">
>         <h2 >Demo Theme Options</h2>
>         <form method="post" action="options.php">
>             <?php
>                 // render the settings for the settings section identified as 'Footer section'
>                 settings_fields('footer_section');
>
>                 //render all of the settings for 'demo-theme-options' sections
>                 do_settings_sections('lindsay-demo-theme-options');
>
>                 // add the submit button to serialize options
>                 submit_button();
>             ?>
>         </form>
>     </div>
> <?php
> }
>
> function demo_footer_message_display(){
> $options = (array)get_option('footer_options');
> $message = $options['message'];
> echo '<input type="text" name="footer_options[message]" id="footer_options_message" value="'.$message.'"/>';
> }
>
> function demo_footer_options_display(){
> echo 'These options are designed to help you control whats dislayed in your footer';
> }
> ```

### footer.php

```
<div id="footer" class="col-md-12"> 
<?php wp_footer() ?>
        <div class="site-info">
            <a href="http://wordpress.org/" title="A Semantic Personal Publishing Platform" rel="generator">Proudly Powered by WordPress</a>
            <span class="sep"> | </span>
            <?php $options = (array) get_option('footer_options');?>
            <?php $message = $options['message'];?>
            <span id="footer-message"><?php echo $message; ?></span>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the words (array) before the method get_option, it shows that he is casting the return as an array (this post says [it's a serialised string](http://wordpress-hackers.1065353.n5.nabble.com/get-option-for-an-element-in-an-array-td25750.html)).The settings api also says that the return type for get_option is "mixed". I would guess that the form is posting the text field that is rendered on the options page saves everything from the post  into the database and when you retrieve it it's easier to cast it to an array to retrieve the "message" portion of the post. Try uncasting it and using "var_dump" to see what it returns and see if you can come up with a better answer than mine :)

```
$options = get_option('footer_options');
var_dump($options)
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion. The result of var_dump($options); is :  array(1) { ["message"]=> string(5) "tests" } after I enter the word tests' into my input field.

I'm still not positive where 'message' comes from...I guess it's part of WordPress's get_options() function?? I just didn't really see any documentation indicating this.

Comment: Try visiting the options page in your wordpress backend, and use inspect element on the form where the text field is. If the input field that corresponds to the footer message has an array with the word message, you will then know if it's set. If it's not there, than it probably implies that it is the "message" of the post action created by the form... Hope this makes sense.

Comment: hmmm, okay. So I replaced all of the spots in my code that say'message' and changed them to test and my code still worked.

So I'm seeing that this is not defined by wordpress and I think when you initially make that $message = $options['message'] statement...your kind of introducing 'message' as a key in the options array...then the value of that key is defined by the value of the input.

Comment: Thanks for helping me look through this.

Comment: Kudos to you for actually trying to learn about how it works :)